# How to indicate a merge-base in log output?

Tags: git

Consider the following:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph branch master
* 6dfe730 (master) Add f
* f06f976 Add e
| * aee36ba (HEAD -> branch) Add f
| * 17eb406 Add e
|/  
* def35c5 Add d
* 98b40fd Add c
* cc90243 (topic) Add b
* e6bf070 Add a
$ git log --oneline --graph branch
* aee36ba (HEAD -> branch) Add f
* 17eb406 Add e
* def35c5 Add d
* 98b40fd Add c
* cc90243 (topic) Add b
* e6bf070 Add a
```

In the log output of the single branch, the branch "topic" is annotated at cc90243.  Is there a reasonable format string to use so that a similar annotation occurs at def35c5 (the merge base of branch and master)?

I imagine output like:

```
$ git log --format="$your_answer_here" branch
* aee36ba (HEAD -> branch) Add f
* 17eb406 Add e
* def35c5 (master~2) Add d
* 98b40fd Add c
* cc90243 (topic) Add b
* e6bf070 Add a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: There's no format string for it, but you can get the info other ways.

`git log` (like everything based off `git rev-list`) starts from the tips you give it, and you haven't told it to look at the `master` commit, so it doesn't even know it exists unless it's in some history you did ask it to walk.

Basically, you can't mark merge bases without examining the mergeable histories to find them.

What you *can* do, though, is get a quick summary of your branch structure with minimum fuss:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all --simplify-by-decoration
```

will show you just the branch tips, merges and splits needed to show the structure, it'll show all the branch tips and merge bases you're interested in.

Comment: I'm not sure about the claim that "git doesn't even know it exists".  If that is the case, why does git annotate cc90243 with "topic"?

Comment: `git log` starting from just the `branch` tip, because that's what you asked it to do, knows about cc90243 because it encountered it on that walk.